# android - Change language AND country programmatically

Tags: android, runtime, locale, region

I'm developing an app that allows user to change language in app's settings. But as long as some countries have 2 or more languages and some languages are used in more than 1 country, I need to use xx-XX format.
For example, users from Belgium can select French or Dutch language.

I use the next code snippet to change language:

```
protected void setLocale() {
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    Locale locale = new Locale(dataManager.getLocale().toLowerCase());
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    conf.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

`dataManager.getLocale()` returns `String` like "fr-BE" or "nl-BE".

I have following resource files:

`values-fr/strings.xml`
`values-fr-rBE/strings.xml`
`values-nl/strings.xml`
`values-nl-rBE/strings.xml`

But even if I set locale to `nl-BE`, it uses strings from `values-nl` directory, but not from `values-nl-rBE`.

So, my question is: "How can I make my app to use resources for certain language AND region in runtime?"

Comment: are you aware that app locale get selected automatically depending upon device locale.

Comment: @RahulTiwari I know, but every my activity invoke `setLocale()` method in `onResume()`. And it works, it uses string for right language, but it doesn't use information about region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the country in the second parameter of `Locale` constructor.

> [**Locale** (String language, String country)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
>   Constructs a new Locale
>   using the specified language and country codes.

For example:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("nl", "BE");
```